# Is there a function/way to automatically add spaces between output?

Tags: php, styles, echo, spacing

In PHP, I'm echoing a mix of strings and variables. I want to be able to automatically add a space between each piece, so I don't have to add a ' ' each time.

Example:

```
echo "This is my" . $string . ".";
```

This will output "This is mystring". is there some function I can wrap the echo in that will automatically place a space between? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user-defined function can automatically add spaces and `echo`:

```
$four_five = 'four five';
echospace('one', 'two', 'three', $four_five, 'six');
// one two three four five six

function echospace () {
    echo join(' ', func_get_args());
}
```

Comment: im sure it has a user case, for the simple string echoing, using your brain and hitting the space bar is a much better idea

Answer (score 1):

no, you should do it your self

```
echo "This is my " . $string . ".";
```

or easier:

```
echo "This is my $string.";
```

some light reading on php strings: [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: Sure, I agree, but not an answer to my question.

Comment: @Egrodo  so you would write\use a function over simply using: `echo "This is my $string."; `

Comment: No, but this is just a proof-of-concept question. Maybe I would in a situation where I was taking in a lot of non-spaced variables and wanted to dynamically space them.

Comment: next time, if you used real examples it would help